# R find maximum sequence length and position

Tags: r, boolean, max, rstudio, sequence

I have a logical vector of TRUEs and FALSEs. Now I want to find out the 10 longest sequences of either TRUEs or FALSE and (most important) their position. With

```
set.seed(123)
data <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 1), size = 3000, replace = TRUE)
reference=3
logical.vec <- data > reference
logical.vec.rle <- rle(logical.vec)
MaxiSequence <- max(logical.vec.rle$length[logical.vec.rle$values=="TRUE"])
```

it returns something like MaxiSequence=55L. My Problem is that

- it only gets the longest sequence
- the position gets lost (I want to know where it is in data or logical.vec)
- it doesn't seem to be right, because in logical.vec.rle$length is a 60 at least (Seen in "Environment" in RStudio). BTW typeof(MaxiSequence) returns integer.

Comment: Perhaps you need  `with(logical.vec.rle, lapply(split(lengths, values), function(x) lapply(sort(x, index.return = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE), head,10)))`

Comment: This is an aside, but my starting point when I am trying to do something new with an existing function is to read the source code for that function. Here's the code behind rle: `function (x) 
{
    if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x)) 
        stop("'x' must be a vector of an atomic type")
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 0L) 
        return(structure(list(lengths = integer(), values = x), 
            class = "rle"))
    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n]
    i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)
    structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]), 
        class = "rle")
}`

Comment: @akrun, thanks a lot. It worked. I just down know how to get one element of the list (for example section $TRUE , first element in list x ). Sorry but I can't find the problem.

Comment: @RHelpPlease  Try `res <- with(logical.vec.rle, lapply(split(lengths, values), function(x) lapply(sort(x, index.return = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE), head,10)));res$`TRUE`$x[1]
#[1] 125`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @akrun. But it returns "unexpected numeric constant" in res

Comment: @RHelpPlease Based on the example you showed, i get `125`

Comment: the index seems to be false. For example when I make a mini-program -_data_seq <- seq(1,10,1) #recent column
reference <- 5
logical_over <- data_seq > reference
logical.vec.rle <- rle(logical_over)
ResultPeak <- with(logical.vec.rle, lapply(split(lengths, values), function(x) lapply(sort(x, index.return = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE), head,3)))_ it returns TRUE: x: 5 at ix:1. I don't get why 1? Because obviously the sequence is "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" and the logical_over is "FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE"

Comment: @akrun you were right. I forgot the quotation marks (RStudio recommended it without and I didn't think about it). Any ideas on the index problem? I want to get the index of the position in "logical.vec"

Comment: You need `sapply(res$"TRUE", "[", 1)`

Comment: yes, please. Thank you soooo much. You made my day

Comment: But this still isn't the index of the position of the peaks in the original data_seq

Comment: @RHelpPlease Can you update your post with the expected output to understand what exactly you wanted?

Comment: sure. for the upper example I expexted FALSE: x:5 at position 1 but TRUE: x: 5 at position ix:6

Comment: I got it. I used cumsum on logical.vec.rle$lengths and put it into logical.vec.rle!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` and its `rleid`-function you can do the following:

```
DT <- data.table(logical.vec, runid = rleid(logical.vec))
DT_stat <- DT[,.(length = .N, position = .I[1], type=logical.vec[1]), by = runid]
# order by length
setorder(DT_stat, -length)
# Get top 3 (or n) by type
DT_stat[, .SD[1:3], type]
```

So this results in:

```
    type runid length position
1:  TRUE     7    125      144
2:  TRUE   103    121     1623
3:  TRUE   115     96     1847
4: FALSE    34      2      717
5: FALSE    80      2     1351
6: FALSE    88      2     1491
```

Comment: That looks really well. But for some reason he doesn't find rleid when I use data.table 1.9.4 . When I try to use 1.9.6 I get _ Reason: Incompatible library version: datatable.so requires version 3.3.0 or later, but libR.dylib provides version 3.2.0 _  and _Paket ‘data.table’ wurde unter R Version 3.3.0 erstellt 
Fehler: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘data.table’ fehlgeschlagen_ which translates to something like _

Comment: `rleid` was introduced in 1.9.6 - regarding your error unfortunately i have no clue. Maybe you find some guidance on the data.table installation guide: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation